# If A and B are mutually independent events, are $\bar {A}$ and $\bar {B}$ mutually independent?

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

If $A$ and $B$ are mutually independent events, are $\bar{A}$ and $\bar{B}$ mutually independent events? Is this an axiom or can it be proved?

I've tried proving it but can't see how I can approach it.

Comment: Hint: first try proving that $A^c$ and $B$ are independent by noting that $$P(B) = P(AB)+P(A^cB) = P(A)P(B)+P(A^cB).$$ Then note that $P(A^c) = P(A^cB) + P(A^cB^c)$ and repeat the same method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$.

Now:     $P(\bar{A}\cap\bar{B})\\=P(\Omega-(A\cup B))\\=1-P(A\cup B)\\=1-(P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B))\\=1-P(A)-P(B)+P(A)P(B)\\=(1-P(A))(1-P(B))\\=P(\bar{A})P(\bar{B})$